# eclipse gdb problem debugging ffmpeg.c

Tags: c, eclipse, gdb, ffmpeg, cygwin

The run configuration works for a given set of arguments while the debug configuration fails.

This is my build configuration for ffmpeg.c
http://pastebin.com/PFM4K4xF

you can view from the build configuration generated . i have set posix style paths for the ffmpeg source.

the debug/run arguments are as `-i Debug/sample2.mpg  -ab 56k -ar 22050 -b 512k -r 30 -s 320x240 Debug/out2.flv`

This all works fine when  i run the program. The output file is generated.

But when i try to debug the ffmpeg.c program

it keeps stopping/hanging at certain instructions and the step over option disables.

like show_banner() and parse_options. ( when i commented out show_banner() it stoped at parse_options.)
more so in show_banner() -> cmdutils-> stops when trying to print swscale

and in parse_options->cmdutils.c-> stops at instruction po->u.func_arg(arg); 
upon further inspection of stepping through i find this going into an infinite loop .

what is this error ? How do i resume stepping over instructions.

Has any one been able to debug completely from start to finish the ffmpeg.c after giving it valid input ? This is to observe the flow of execution based on the input's given.